# Why does an alarm go "off" when it really goes on?

Tags: technology

Why is an alarm said to go "off" when it really is being turned "on"?

Comment: Uh... Yeah, I've got nothing.

Comment: This more goes with etymology and phrasiology, but also it's world building that people should learn to do. The basic answer from memory is that in the past an alarm would knock something off of something to turn on when the phrase was coined, it wasn't talking about the alarm being on or off, but the mechanism which caused it to be on or off, which just happened to have something on making the alarm off, or that thing off making the alarm on. I could google search this in 10 secs but i dun wanna...

Comment: It's OED's *colloq.1. orig. U.S.* definition: **go off** - *The action or fact of making a start; commencement, beginning; the moment of doing this, the starting point* (for which their first usage citation is 1830).

Comment: Because when you subsequently whack it across the room it is *off the table*.

Answer (score 4):

***[Go off](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=go%20off)*** meaning, start, depart is a very old idiomatic usage tha  dates to the 17th century:

> - 1570s, of firearms, etc., "explode, be discharged;" see go (v.) + off (adv.); ***meaning "depart" is c. 1600;*** that of "deteriorate in condition" is from 1690s; that of "reprimand" is from 1941 (originally with at, since c. 2000 more often with on).

Etymonline

I think that in the case of an alarm, the meaning ,  in the figurative sense, is that of a firearm:

***[Go off](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go--off)***:

> - to explode, fire, or perform or begin to function abruptly.

Dictionary.com